# Set up usb wifi dongle to automatically connect to specific secured network

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, security, wireless-bridge

I have a Belkin 802.11g usb network adapter that I no longer need (specifically: F5D7050B), and I have a secured wireless network at home.  Rather than hand out the password when I have guests, I'd like to be able to hand out the network adapter for someone to plug in, and the adapter will be pre-configured with the right information to be able to connect.

Is this possible? (I suspect not, but there's no harm in asking).  Some ideas I've had:

- Custom firmware, but the only things I can find are for routers (ie dd-wrt or tomato)
- Exempting the MAC address of the device from needing to encrypt traffic (but that's just not how wireless encryption works - I'd still need a different SSID, which perhaps a nicer router could do

If (and only if) it's not possible, does anyone sell a device that will do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not with your dongle. You need a portable wireless access point/bridge/ethernet adapter that will connect your client plug-and-play to your network.

Basically a bridge connects to a pre-configured wireless network and connects the client by ethernet.

---

An example of a Portable Wireless Ethernet Adapter is the [Asus WL-330](http://www.asus.com/Networks/WiFi_Networking/WL330g/), but I imagine there are more vendors out there that sell this kind of product.

[image]

Comment: Ah, of course.  I use these for pair of wifi-only computers here at the college so that they come online right away at the log in prompt and active directory is available to authenticate users when they sign in.  The ones we use do it all via usb, so there's no extra power connection and only one wire to the PC.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Just giving an example of how to accomplish it. ;) If you have hardware that works even better, I'd love to know!